# output of one in the shiny server to be used inside another output

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

i has a question whether the output of one can be used in another output ? I wish to use the result of output$mysum to be used in my output$condition

```
 output$condition= renderText({
        if (output$mysum <20) {
          print("The sum of the time is less than 20")

        }
      })

      output$mysum <- renderText({

      x=input$number
      x=x+1
        }
      })
```

Comment: I've had the same annoying issue before and never solved it. This is definitely bounty worthy (for me at least) if no one answers. I look forward to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [reactive expression](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/) whose value you can use in any `output`. For instance:

```
sumone <- reactive({
  input$number+1
})
output$condition <- renderText({
   if (sumone() < 20) {
     print("The sum of the time is less than 20")
   }
})
output$mysum <- renderText({
   sumone()
})
```

Comment: Very nice, helpful example.

Comment: @KienWei Glad it helped. Consider accepting the answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

If let's say i get a value speed from input$year as 2015, then i want to use this value as a condition factor in output$mysum. It can be done with the reactive too ?

```
output$condition <- renderText({
 if(input$year==2015){
 speed=as.numeric(sqldf("select ave_speed from newdataset where [month]=12 
 AND [day]=30 AND [regionid]=16"))
        }

   }
})
output$mysum <- renderText({
    if(speed<30){
  month=as.numeric(sqldf("select month from newdataset where [month]=12 AND 
  [day]=30 AND [regionid]=16"))
     }
})
```